# Visual Studio Online Build and Release Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, build, azure-devops

We were originally using Start-AzureWebsite and Stop-AzureWebsite in a powershell script to start and stop web apps in Azure before publishing.  In the VSO build it was using Azure Powershell, the connection type was Azure Classic.  Microsoft recommended switching to Start-AzureRmWebApp and Stop-AzureRmWebApp which uses the Azure Resource Manager.  We modified the Azure Powershell step in the build to have a connection type of Azure Resource Manager, and selected the correct subscription.  When it calls our external script using the script path, it appears as though the authentication is not being passed on to the script, we get the error "Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login." when it tries to execute the command to start/stop the websites.  How do we get the authentication to persist down to the script being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out instead of using Connect-AzureRMAccount i needed to be using Add-AzureRmAccount, once i changed that i can now connect and start/stop App Services! Thank you for the help. – Link

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the connection get lost, it should work if you dotsource the script to invoke it. However:

I would suggest to create a service principal within the AAD that is linked to your subscription and grant it access to your web app. Then you should use the *existing* **Azure App Service Manage** Task to start / stop your app:

[image]
By the way, starting / stopping / deploying a web app should be part of a **Release Definition** / Step - not build.
 -

Comment: We don't use the Azure App Service Manage functionality because that only allows it to do one at a time.  We have about 15 services that it stops/starts.  With the PowerShell we can loop through and create jobs to allow it to kick them all off at the same time and then waits for them all to finish.  It shaves about 10 minutes off the process by doing it this way.  As for dotsourceing the script, we use the Script Type of ScriptFilePath and point to a script we have in source control.  I am not sure how we would dotsource that?

Comment: In this case I would pass the ClientId and ClientSecret of a service principal to each script that uses Azure cmdlets that require authentication and login.

Comment: I have tried using the service principal method but am apparently missing a step somewhere.  When I attempt to log in through PowerShell I get the following error message, AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the cc0bbcdd-639b-4d8c-9dd7-9bf9b8873a99 directory.  If I go to the Active Directory with that ID and look at AIM the Service Principal I created is in there with Contributor Access Rights.  All searches for the error show old results from the old dashboards.  Any guidance where to find more information on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Ensure you are using the right cmdlet to authenticate and that the ClientID and ClientSecret is correct. Also ensure the princpal has access to the resource you want to work with.

Comment: I am using Connect-AzureRmAccount cmdlet to connect, and have checked the other items as well (if I change the client id or client secret I get a different error message, about the id and password not being valid, so pretty sure they are ok), if I go to the Subscription in question, and click on Access Control (AIM), the service principal is listed as having contributor access.  If I go to the Active Directory, I do not see anywhere to show service principal access, it only shows users, and the service principal is not listed.

Comment: You have to go to the Application Tab. However, can you try to run the script locally (without VSTS) and ensure that it works with the service principal?

Comment: Turns out instead of using Connect-AzureRMAccount i needed to be using Add-AzureRmAccount, once i changed that i can now connect and start/stop App Services!  Thank you for the help.